# how to get the label, not the value on select field jet form builder from crocoblock

Tags: wordpress, forms, select

I've a booking form where the data will be sent to WhatsApp, one of the select fields takes data from the custom post type, when I do the submit action it turns out the data taken is a value in the form of a number.

[image]

is it possible to display my Label data instead of value?

Thank you in advance